# Jquery autoplay and autoplay next song

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I can't seem to find useful code to make my playlist autoplay the first song when site loads and then when the song finishes, autoplay the next song.

I got this code following a tutorial, but they did not include these functions. I have looks all over and the code I have seen has not helped me with my issue.

```
var audio;

//Hide pause buton
$('#pause').hide();

//Initialize Audio
initAudio($('#playlist li:first-child'));


//Initializer Function
function initAudio(element){
    var song = element.attr('song')
    var title = element.text();

    //Create audio object
    audio = new Audio('media/' + song);

    if(!audio.currentTime){
        $('#duration').html('0.00');
    }

    $('#audio-player .title').text(title);

    $('#playlist li') .removeClass('active');
        element.addClass('active');

    }

    //PLay Button
    $('#play') .click(function(){
        audio.play();
        $('#play') .hide();
        $('#pause') .show();
        $('#duration') .fadeIn(400);
        showDuration();

    });


    //Pause Button
    $('#pause') .click(function(){
        audio.pause();
        $('#pause') .hide();
        $('#play') .show();


    });

    //Stop Button
    $('#stop') .click(function(){
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
        $('#pause') .hide();
        $('#play') .show();
        $('#duration') .fadeOut(400);

    });



    //Next Button
    $('#next').click(function(){
        audio.pause();
        var next = $('#playlist li.active').next();
        if (next.length == 0) {
            next = $('#playlist li:first-child');
        }
        initAudio(next);
        audio.play();
        showDuration();
    });

    //Prev Button
    $('#prev') .click(function(){
        audio.pause();
        var prev = $('#playlist li.active').prev();
        if (next.length == 0){
            prev = $('playlist li:last-child');
        }
        initAudio (prev);
        audio.play();
        showDuration();
    });



    //Time Duration

    function showDuration(){
        $(audio).bind('timeupdate', function(){
            //Get Hours & Minutes
            var s = parseInt (audio.currentTime % 60);
            var m = parseInt ((audio.currentTime)/ 60) % 60;
            //Add 0 if less than 10
            if(s < 10){
                s = '0' + s;

            }
            $('#duration').html (m + '.' + s);
            var value = 0;
            if(audio.currentTime > 0) {
                value = Math.floor((100 / audio.duration) * audio.currentTime);

            }
            $('#progress').css('width',value+'%');
        });
    }

    //Playlist Song Click
    $('#playlist li').click(function () {
        audio.pause();
        initAudio($(this));
        $('#play').hide();
        $('#pause').show();
        $('#duration').fadeIn(400);
        audio.play();
        showDuration();
    });


    //Volume Control
    $('#volume').change(function(){
    audio.volume = parseFloat(this.value / 10);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start playing the audio sounds pretty straightforward : you can trigger a click on the play button using

```
$('#play').trigger('click');
```

Playing the next song when one is over can be done in `showDuration()` :

```
if( audio.currentTime >= audio.duration) $('#next').trigger('click');
```

Comment: You are brilliant! I got the next song to play after one ends, but I couldn't seem to get the first song to autoplay when the site loads to work? I may be putting in the wrong spot, any suggestions?

Comment: No, the code posted above is literally all the code for my .js (I am super noob at this fyi) Should I add that somewhere?

Comment: yep, you have to wait for the DOM (the document) to be ready before executing any script on it. Two solutions : 1) place your script (or call your JS file) at the end of the body, just before the `</body>` tag (that's my favorite). 2) Use `$(function(){ ` http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I have the script right before </body> still doesn't start the song on page load. (I think i may just be putting $('#play').trigger('click'); in the wrong place or something?

Comment: Well of course, you have to put it after the click function has been bond to the button, that is, after calling initAudio(). If that's the case, I'm running out of ideas. Try to `console.log` stuff at various places...